# how to solve the limit of an integral with an unknown function?

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

With $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, solve :
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} f(x)\tan^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

But I have no idea where to start. I think I have to do an integration by parts and apply a convergence theorem, but I can't understand how it's possible to calculate $f(x)$ when it's not defined.

Comment: What is $L^1(x)$?

Comment: The space L1 is the space of ℝ-valued functions whose absolute value (or the space of ℂ-valued functions whose modulus) is integrable in the Lebesgue sense.

Comment: First think about it if $f=1$. Then apply some simple bounds, given $f$ is integrable. *You don’t need to evaluate the integral*. You need to show it (vanishes) (diverges) (tends to something else)

Comment: Use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: And in general on this site, it’s good to talk a little bit more, to flesh out the post with context and ideas and progress, or even with discussions of what you know / have learnt and how you think this problem is related (after all, you probably got it from a textbook or a teacher at the end of a chapter / class...)

Comment: I think you can exchange the limit and the integral to get $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}f(x)\tan^\infty xdx=0$, don't know if this is useful though, probably will have to prove something about $f(x)$ that doesn't make the integral diverge.

Comment: You can do it with the dominated convergence theorem, sure. This case however is simple enough that you can do it with no measure theory at all, really, just the knowledge that $\int|f|$ is finite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for all $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ we have that $\tan x\in(-1,1)$, and so in particular also that $\tan^n x\in(-1,1)$. This means that for all $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$,

$$\left\lvert f(x)\tan^n x\right\rvert\leq\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert.$$

Since $f$ is $L^1$, we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem, which yields that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}f(x)\tan^n x~\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=\int_{\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}f(x)\cdot0~\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=0.$$